# What is the difference b/w <<endl; & ;?

Tags: computer-engineering

Language = C++

There are 2 types of statements I noticed for taking in output.

1)

```
int x=3,y=4;

if(x>y)

cout<<“x is greater than y”<<endl;

else

cout<<“y is greater than x”<<endl;
```

2. 

```
int a,b,c;

cout<<“Enter 3 numbers”;

cin>>a>>b>>c;
```

In the 2nd statement , it is not written <<endl; but only “;” .
I noticed there is no error in compiling. What is the difference between writing the two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`endl` is the end of the line keyword/constant for the C++ compiler.

The only difference, is that when you are prompted to enter numbers you will continue from the same line.

if `cout<<“Enter 3 numbers”<<endl;` is used then the numbers will be entered below.

[diffrence between endl and \n.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n)